# Find the coordinates of the point at the tail of the fish

Tags: python, opencv, pointers, coordinates

I tried it a number of times and consulted some solutions but it really didn't work out as expected. Hope people can give me the solution and some example.
I've attached a picture if you want to use it to run code for your program.

I want to find the coordinates of the point like the picture

[image: describe image]

[image]

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: I used some OpenCV support algorithms such as cv2.conveditydefect but could not know the exact coordinates of that point.

Comment: My idea is to find the convex hull and approximate to an ellipse and finally find the largest radius to get the head and the tail position.

Comment: Maybe you can use https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html

Comment: thanks for your idea so much, can you do some sample rounds for me. hope you help me

Comment: First try following the tutorial above with your image. You can also use the `skimage` library which contains useful algorithms for image processing.

Comment: thank you very much , I will find out what you have suggested to me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i don't have any concrete idea for this yet, what i did is use the algorithm of the cv2.conveditydefect function to plot the points on the figure but there is a point i cant control the number of points and know which coordinates  corresponding to that point

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you exactly want; whether all points within the gap or the one in the innermost curve of the gap, or something else.
Regardless, I hope you find this a little helpful even if you are not trying to do the second.

Since I don't have your original image and assuming that the image you are working with doesn't contain the red circle, I downloaded your image and erased part of the red circle into something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySuY7.jpg (apologies for I do not have enough rep to embed images)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread("Inkedfish.jpg")

# some preprocessing
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2 = cv2.dilate(img2, (3,3))
img2 = cv2.blur(img2, (3, 3))
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img2, 10, 255, 0)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours = contours[0]

hull = cv2.convexHull(contours, returnPoints=False)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(contours, hull)

# there are 3 most plausible points at the tail:
# the edges of the tail, and the innermost curve.
# Based on the image we can infer that the
# point on the innermost curve should come before
# the other two thus we do [-3]
contour_idxs = np.sort(defects[:,:,2], axis=1)
point = contours[contour_idxs[-3, 0], 0]
cv2.circle(img, point, 5, (0,0,255), -1)
```

result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE7BJ.png

EDIT:
Changing cv2.dilate to `img2 = cv2.morphologyEx(img2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, (3, 3))` seem to work as intended.

Comment: Very nice snippet!

Comment: i thank you for giving me the solution but when i ran this code it came out not as expected , can you tell me the reason is not sincerely thank you .

Comment: result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkIkr.png

Comment: @Mirote I suppose the difference in the result is due to the different size of the images used. You can check this by printing the image shape.

Comment: i ran and it was as successful as expected . And especially since it's only true of the image I provided, with another similar image, it's wrong. But also really thank you for your help.